# Selecting data from multiple tables based on PK - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am looking to select data from multiple tables and insert into respective text boxes. I can have one table that hold all the data, but as I want to apply normalization to the data sets, I will have to split the data.

I already know that I can use :

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE Username = UserNametxt.Text.Trim()
```

and then addWithValue etc.

How would I do this using a PK from one table linked to other tables as a FK?

Table **users**:

```
    id (pk)
    email
    password
    last_login
```

Table **address**:

```
    id (fk to users.id)
    houseNumber
    StreetName
    City
```

Table **postcode**:

```
    id (fk to users.id)
    PostCode
```

The above is a rough sample of what the data tables will be.

Comment: Your tables does not have a good normalization. Each table must have it's Id column as primary key. And your Address and PostCode tables must have it's primary Id's in User table

Comment: They are just rough tables, I forgot to add the PK and FK, my bad.

Comment: Even so, I didn't see till now multiple users to have the same address to expand these data into multiple tables... But, you might build a view on your server and to update tables thru that view, maybe using a Stored Procedure, depending on your's SQL provider (MS, Firebird, Oracle, Postgres and so on)

Comment: You mean an `JOIN`? `SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN address ON address.id = users.id WHERE ...`

Comment: Nah, I don't think I need a join. I was thinking along the lines of "select * from table1, table 2, where PK = something. I want to use the pk as the condition to call the data from multiple tables based on relationship. I'm not certain that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should change the structure of your tables. In order to properly normalize DB, tables address and postcode should have their own id (PK), which does not depend on data from other tables.
If you leave it that way, you won't get rid of data duplication (which is one of the main reasons to normalize DB)

So it would look like that:

Table addresses:

```
id (PK)
userId (FK)
houseNumber
streetName
city
```

Table postcodes:

```
id (PK)
userId (FK)
postCode
```

And then you need to get information. You need to use JOIN to somehow connect tables and get information you need

```
SELECT * FROM users
LEFT JOIN addresses ON adresses.UserId=users.Id
LEFT JOIN postcodes ON postcodes.UserId=users.Id
WHERE ...
```